# Flickering GUI Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop

Tags: 20.04, desktop-environments, flicker

I installed fresh copy of Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop version for more than a month, and everything was okay. Suddenly 3 days ago (without any new installations), everything became crazy whenever (specially just after the booting and login) i open the Terminal, Thunderbird, Firefox ... or any program i installed the tabs, the side bar, the mouse cursor shake and flicker, even any words in the Terminal are displayed in weird chars:

[image]

The image supposed to be listing of /var/log path!

I have to close all running programs "terminal, thunderbird, files explorer, firefox..." and re-open them one by one to make it stable again, otherwise it will lead to make the whole thing to freeze

I moved out my Hard disk to another laptop, as i thought it is something related to HW issue, but same issue.

Help Please!

Comment: Does it work as expected (as before) when booting an older kernel?

Comment: Didn't try older kernel booting, but the booting is normal yes. But this issue usually  happens just after I login after the booting.

Comment: So try an older kernel. There were some recent kernel version pushed trough regular updates that created similar issues for some users. If an older kernel works I recommended using it and hopefully it'll work just fine in the next update.

Comment: I found only one older version **5.8.0-49-generic**, and my current one is **5.8.0-50-generic**. And here is the crazy part. This issue used to show up in every booting. When i changed to the old one "49", it showed up, switched back to the recent 50 the issue fixed!!, rebooted with 50 again, the issue showed up again!, switched back to 49, and the issue is gone!!!

Answer (score 1):

I got **exactly** this problem today, on my ubuntu 20.04.1 system with kernel 5.8.0.50-generic! I tried all sorts of solutions offered on the net, but the only thing that worked was to boot into 5.8.0-49 once and then back to 5.8.0-50. Just as MohammedSimba suggested! I guess I will hold off re-booting for as long as possible ...

Comment: In my case 5.8.0-50 was okay till the rebooting, switched back to 5.8.0-49 and it is the current one running and booted normally and i am holding off the rebooting as well.

Comment: The problem came back as soon as I started Firefox :-(. I have now managed to remove the flicker by disabling H/W acceleration in the Firefox performance settings, and also switch from X11 to Wayland. You will have to logout of X after changing the Firefox settings before the flicker disappears. My guess is that Firefox H/W acceleration somehow corrupts the Intel drivers. FYI, I am using a 4K monitor with 200% HDPI and a i7-4790S (Intel HD4600).